# Draw $r ≤ 3 + 2\sin (\theta)$

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, parametric, parametrization

Currently I'm stuck at this fairly easy task. All I have to do is sketch the region $r \le 3+2\sin \theta$. My guess would be that the circle has the origin $(0,3)$ with $r = 2$, as I use the formula $y = b + r \sin \theta$. But that's completely wrong.

EDIT: I am interesting in the *right procedure* for drawing a region like this, not the actual plot itself. This was a question for a previous test without the use of calculators.

Comment: That equation does not define a circle. Why do you say it is a circle?

Comment: That curve is not a circle (or rather, that region is not a disc).

Comment: If you're stuck, plot some points for various values of $\theta$ and see if you notice anything

Comment: Oh sorry! I meant region instead of circle. I have plotted with desmos several different sin (θ) and also cos (θ), but I can't see a pattern. Only that sin (θ) is shifted upwards with origin (0,1) and cos (θ) to the right at (1,0).

Comment: [Desmos](https://www.desmos.com/calculator) is a good tool to get an idea about the shape of a curve.

Answer (score 5):

This equation is describing a [limacon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lima%C3%A7on).

You mention that you have to sketch a circle, but it's not a circle. You can find the drawing corresponding to the equation [here](https://www.mathway.com/popular-problems/Precalculus/436830).

$r=3+2\sin \theta$ is an equation that require to use [polar coordinates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polar_coordinate_system#Polar_equation_of_a_curve) to draw the graph. Be sure to be familiar with it.

Pay attention, in your title you are using "=" but "≤" in your question. "=" will be a line whereas "≤" will be the surface inside that line.

Comment: Thanks, I have been sloppy with the sign and changed it in the title. That's probably a better way of frasing my question: I don't know ''how'' to plot r ≤ 3+2sin (θ) using polar coordinates. I know that x = r*cos (θ), y = r*sin (θ), I have tried squaring the term, still can't draw the region.

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes a picture is worth 1000 words:

[image]

If you want to work "by hand," you can make a traditional (rectilinear) plots of $r$, $x$ and $y$ (actually, you only need $x$ and $y$), then sample pairs of coordinates at different $\theta$s and transfer them to your polar graph.

[image]

Comment: Thank you, I see I didn't ask my question properly. I know what the region looks like, I just don't know how to draw it by hand without plotting various values of phi.

Comment: I don't think anyone knows how to draw it by hand without plotting various values of $\phi$.